# PHP Regular expression in mysql to check for name contains accented letters and length of name greater than 5

Tags: php, mysql, regex

How do I write query with regular expression for the following scenario.

```
id name
1  Müllere
2  Kees
3  Hernández
4  Björn
```

Given above is my MySQL table. I want to get result, name contains accented letters and length of name greater than 5

Comment: Can a 'name' contain anything other than accented and non-accented characters. If not, I suggest you dwell on that fact a little while.

Comment: Yes the name can contain non-accented characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
Select * from test where Length(name) > '5' and name REGEXP '[accentedcharacters]+';
```

Comment: @ Malai: this is not working Select * from test where name REGEXP '[accentedcharacters]+';

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE length(name) > 5 and name REGEXP '[accentedcharacters]+'
```

However, I am not sure about mysql REGEXP for accented characters

[1] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: this is not working Select * from test where name REGEXP '[accentedcharacters]+';

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM letters
+--------+
| letter |
+--------+
| '      |
| -      |
| a      |
| b      |
| c      |
| d      |
| e      |
| f      |
| g      |
| h      |
| i      |
| j      |
| k      |
| l      |
| m      |
| n      |
| o      |
| p      |
| q      |
| r      |
| s      |
| t      |
| u      |
| v      |
| w      |
| x      |
| y      |
| z      |
| å      |
| ä      |
| ö      |
| ÿ      |
+--------+

SELECT *
  FROM letters
 WHERE letter NOT REGEXP '[a-z\'|A-Z\-]';
+--------+
| letter |
+--------+
| å      |
| ä      |
| ö      |
| ÿ      |
+--------+
```